Nostr OAuth 2 authentication using Fastapi
I liked the idea of being able to authenticate using your own private key using Nostr protocol. The idea is based on events, so you prove your identity by signing an event.
It's close to Wallet Connect used in web3 and Metamask but not related to cryptocurrency directly, and it's used in Nostr social network.
I've created this code based on Fastapi Authentication Tutorial
I would like to know how far or my code is close to OAuth 2.0 specifications. I'm using the user public key as a username and the signature of the event signed as the password.
I'm also passing the JSON-formatted event data to make it easier to validate without storing the historical data of events in the backend.
The code is below and more details in this code snippet with test vector
# Based on https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/oauth2-jwt/
# and https://github.com/monty888/monstr/blob/master/src/monstr/event/event.py

from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
from typing import Annotated

import jwt
import hashlib
import json
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, HTTPException, status
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordBearer, OAuth2PasswordRequestForm
from jwt.exceptions import InvalidTokenError
from pydantic import BaseModel
from passlib.context import CryptContext

import secp256k1
from fastapi import Form

# to get a string like this run:
# openssl rand -hex 32
SECRET_KEY = "497664fb69cf00d6fa47eacb8401d421cc22a01beefe0041e9a5882a1252a538"
ALGORITHM = "HS256"
ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES = 30

## List of banned accounts
banned_list = []

class CustomOAuth2PasswordRequestForm(OAuth2PasswordRequestForm):
    """Custom OAuth2 password request form with additional JSON data."""
    def __init__(
        self,
        username: str = Form(...),
        password: str = Form(...),
        json_data: str = Form(...),
    ):
        super().__init__(username=username, password=password)
        self.json_data = json_data

class Token(BaseModel):
    """Token model for JWT token response."""
    access_token: str
    token_type: str

class TokenData(BaseModel):
    """Token data model for decoded JWT token."""
    username: str | None = None

class User(BaseModel):
    """User model with public key."""
    user_pubkey: str

class UserInDB(User):
    """User model with hashed password."""
    hashed_password: str

class PublicKeyRequest(BaseModel):
    """Request model for public key."""
    pubkey: str

class EventToSign(BaseModel):
    """Event model to be signed."""
    id: str
    pubkey: str
    created_at: int
    kind: int
    tags: list
    content: str
    sig: str

pwd_context = CryptContext(schemes=["bcrypt"], deprecated="auto")

oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="token")

app = FastAPI()

class Event:
    """Event class to handle Nostr events."""
    def __init__(
        self,
        id=None,
        sig=None,
        kind=None,
        content=None,
        tags=None,
        pub_key=None,
        created_at=None,
    ):
        self._id = id
        self._sig = sig
        self._kind = kind
        self._created_at = created_at
        self._content = str(content)
        self._pub_key = pub_key
        self._tags = tags

    def serialize(self):
        """Serialize the event data to JSON."""
        if self._pub_key is None:
            raise Exception("Event::serialize can't be done unless pub key is set")

        ret = json.dumps(
            [0, self._pub_key, self._created_at, self._kind, self._tags, self._content],
            separators=(",", ":"),
            ensure_ascii=False,
        )

        return ret

    def _get_id(self):
        """Generate the event ID based on the serialized event data."""
        evt_str = self.serialize()
        self._id = hashlib.sha256(evt_str.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest()
        return self._id

    def sign(self, event_id, priv_key):
        """Sign the event with the given private key."""
        pk = secp256k1.PrivateKey()
        pk.deserialize(priv_key)

        id_bytes = bytes.fromhex(event_id)
        sig = pk.schnorr_sign(id_bytes, bip340tag="", raw=True)
        sig_hex = sig.hex()

        self._sig = sig_hex
        return self._sig

    def is_valid(self):
        """Verify the event signature."""
        pub_key = secp256k1.PublicKey(bytes.fromhex("02" + self._pub_key), raw=True)

        _return = pub_key.schnorr_verify(
            msg=bytes.fromhex(self._id),
            schnorr_sig=bytes.fromhex(self._sig),
            bip340tag="",
            raw=True,
        )

        return _return

def compute_event_id(event_data):
    """Compute the event ID based on the event data."""
    event = Event(
        kind=event_data["kind"],
        content=event_data["content"],
        tags=event_data["tags"],
        pub_key=event_data["pubkey"],
        created_at=event_data["created_at"],
    )
    event_id = event._get_id()
    return event_id

def compute_event_sig(event_id, private_key):
    """Compute the event signature based on the event ID and private key."""
    event = Event()
    return event.sign(event_id, private_key)

def verify_nostr_event(sig, event):
    """Verify the Nostr event signature."""
    try:
        event_data = json.loads(event)

        public_key = event_data["pubkey"]
        signature = event_data["sig"]
        signature = sig
        event_id = event_data["id"]
        content = event_data["content"]
        created_at = event_data["created_at"]
        kind = event_data["kind"]
        tags = event_data["tags"]

        data = {
            "pubkey": public_key,
            "created_at": created_at,
            "kind": kind,
            "tags": tags,
            "content": content,
        }

        serialized_data = json.dumps(data, sort_keys=True, separators=(",", ":"))

        data_bytes = serialized_data.encode("utf-8")

        event = Event(
            id=event_id,
            sig=sig,
            pub_key=public_key,
            created_at=created_at,
            kind=kind,
            content=content,
            tags=tags,
        )

        event_id2 = event._get_id()

        if event_id != event_id2:
            print("verify_nostr_event: Event invalid != hashlib")
            return False

        if not event.is_valid():
            print("verify_nostr_event: Event invalid: verifying_key")
            return False

        print("verify_nostr_event: Event valid")
        return True
    except (KeyError, json.JSONDecodeError, ecdsa.BadSignatureError):
        return False

def verify_password(plain_password, hashed_password):
    """Verify the given plain password against the hashed password."""
    return pwd_context.verify(plain_password, hashed_password)

def get_password_hash(password):
    """Hash the given password."""
    return pwd_context.hash(password)

def get_user(pubkey):
    """Get user by public key."""
    return {"user_pubkey": pubkey}

def authenticate_user(sig, event):
    """Authenticate user by verifying the event signature."""
    event_json = json.loads(event)

    user = event_json["pubkey"]

    if not user:
        return False
    if not verify_nostr_event(sig, event):
        return False
    return user

def create_access_token(data: dict, expires_delta: timedelta | None = None):
    """Create a JWT access token."""
    to_encode = data.copy()
    if expires_delta:
        expire = datetime.now(timezone.utc) + expires_delta
    else:
        expire = datetime.now(timezone.utc) + timedelta(minutes=15)
    to_encode.update({"exp": expire})
    encoded_jwt = jwt.encode(to_encode, SECRET_KEY, algorithm=ALGORITHM)
    return encoded_jwt

async def get_current_user(token: Annotated[str, Depends(oauth2_scheme)]):
    """Get the current user from the JWT token."""
    credentials_exception = HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        detail="Could not validate credentials",
        headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
    )
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
        username: str = payload.get("sub")
        if username is None:
            raise credentials_exception
        token_data = TokenData(username=username)
    except InvalidTokenError:
        print("credentials_exception")
        raise credentials_exception
    user = get_user(token_data.username)
    if user is None:
        raise credentials_exception
    print("get_current_user: returning user")
    return user

async def get_current_active_user(
    current_user: Annotated[User, Depends(get_current_user)],
):
    """Get the current active user, ensuring they are not banned."""
    print("get_current_active_user: inside it")
    if current_user in banned_list:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Inactive user")
    return current_user

@app.post("/token")
async def login_for_access_token(
    form_data: Annotated[CustomOAuth2PasswordRequestForm, Depends()],
) -> Token:
    """Login endpoint to get an access token."""
    user = authenticate_user(form_data.password, form_data.json_data)
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Incorrect username or password",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
        )
    access_token_expires = timedelta(minutes=ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRE_MINUTES)
    access_token = create_access_token(
        data={"sub": form_data.username}, expires_delta=access_token_expires
    )
    return Token(access_token=access_token, token_type="bearer")

@app.get("/users/me/", response_model=User)
async def read_users_me(
    current_user: Annotated[User, Depends(get_current_active_user)],
):
    """Get the current user's information."""
    return current_user

@app.get("/users/me/items/")
async def read_own_items(
    current_user: Annotated[User, Depends(get_current_active_user)],
):
    """Get the current user's items."""
    return [{"item_id": "Foo", "owner": current_user}]

@app.post("/get_event_to_sign", response_model=EventToSign)
async def get_event_to_sign(public_key_request: PublicKeyRequest):
    """Generate an event to be signed by the user."""
    pubkey = public_key_request.pubkey
    created_at = int(datetime.now(timezone.utc).timestamp())
    kind = 1
    tags = []
    content = "Please sign this event"

    event_data = {
        "pubkey": pubkey,
        "created_at": created_at,
        "kind": kind,
        "tags": tags,
        "content": content,
    }

    serialized_data = json.dumps(event_data, sort_keys=True, separators=(",", ":"))
    data_bytes = serialized_data.encode("utf-8")

    computed_event_id = compute_event_id(event_data)

    event = {
        "id": computed_event_id,
        "pubkey": pubkey,
        "created_at": created_at,
        "kind": kind,
        "tags": tags,
        "content": content,
        "sig": "",  # The signature will be added by the user
    }

    return event


